# Concatenate multiple rows from inside a correlated 'group by' subquery into a single text string

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-concat, correlated-subquery

Similar questions have been asked before but I am specifically looking for an answer to do much the same with a correlated subquery.

I am doing this on SQL Server, and I cannot utilize stored procedure or temp table creation approach.

For those familiar with Client Matter billing; I have formulated a 'group by' query using row_number technique to return me back the top 3 performers for each unique clientmatter, summing their amounts over a period of time.

This gives me something like this:

```
  clientmatterno  attorneyname  amount seq_num
  111111.00001     John Doe     $30,000 1
  111111.00001     Mark Tim     $23,000 2
  111111.00001     Jane Sue     $15,000 3
  111111.00001     Mary Ann      $5,000 4
  222221.00501     John Doe     $35,000 1
  222221.00501     David Hu     $30,000 2
  444444.00003     Shelly Y     $50,000 1
```

I think, I would have to first do a group by clause to sum up the amounts for each attorney in order to find the totals and hence get the correct seq_num to appear across. 
 
I am now trying to use this subquery results to do the string concatenation such that I get the following results:

```
  111111.00001     John Doe|Mark Tim|Jane Sue   
  222221.00501     John Doe|David Hu
  444444.00003     Shelly Y
```

The Query that I think will work, seeing past questions on this topic:

```
select subq.clientmatterno as [Id], 
, 
     STUFF(
         (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + subq.attorneyname
          FROM ????
          WHERE ????
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS TopPerformers
from ( 
SELECT clientmatterno, attorneyname, sum(amount), 
 row_number() over (partition by clientmatterno order by sum(amount) desc) as seq_num
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY clientmatterno, attorneyname
) as subq
where seq_num <= 3
group by clientmatterno
```

My problem is on how to connect and build up the STUFF function. The error is very simple: I cannot seem to use the subquery set 'subq' in the FROM clause inside the STUFF function. 
I have not tried out XML FOR Auto approach.

Comment: what's wrong with your query? what's the output? did you try to use a CTE instead of a subquery?

Comment: I am not much familiar using STUFF, so I am unable to create a proper WHERE clause to join the two identical rows in order to get concatenation going. It's complaining the subq does not exist.

Comment: Using For XML Auto is a valid way of concatenating SQL data into a single string. Have you tried this? It should work!

Comment: if the system is complainig it produces an error message that it is extremely useful when solving issues... post that message!

Comment: Please post the entire query that is producing the error and the exact error message, rather than individual pieces that work fine on their own.

Comment: added the entire query for what matters, and ???? indicates where I am having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a common table expression instead of a derived table:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT 
       clientmatterno, 
       attorneyname, 
       sum(amount) amount, 
       seq = row_number() over (partition by clientmatterno order by sum(amount) desc) 
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY clientmatterno, attorneyname
)

SELECT 
    clientmatterno,
    STUFF(
       (
       SELECT '|' + attorneyname
        FROM cte
        WHERE clientmatterno = a.clientmatterno
       AND seq <= 3
        FOR XML PATH ('')
       ), 1, 1, ''
    )  AS Attorneynames
FROM cte AS a
GROUP BY clientmatterno
```

Comment: Isn't that approach same as creating a temp table?

Comment: @IkramM. No, because it doesn't create any temp table. Just give it a try :)

Comment: Tried this and I get an error message: Column 'cte.attorneyname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Was able to send an ado.net request through asp.net and worked great. Initially had the alias wrong hence gave me the invalid error.

Comment: It solved the query problem but it hogged the database resource and I was told to Undo :-(

Comment: @IkramM. Ah ok. Yes, this query is probably pretty costly due to the stuff/xml processing. It might be better to handle this kind of grouping in the client-side presentation layer.